# finding substrings in strings w/java

Tags: java, string, substring

How would I find multiple substrings inside of a string?  Let's compare it to gene sequencing.  You have a string:  TTCGAGATGCTGATTGACATGTTAGTAG.  I've figured out how to find the start of my sequence (ATG is the starting point) and the end of the sequence using only TGA.  I can't figure out how to repeat the process for TAA and TGA. Is it possible to have all 3 substrings in my line of code looking for my end point?

```
String genome = input.nextLine();
    //first check: see if the genome contains the marker "ATG"  
    if (genome.contains("atg")){
    //if the genome contains "ATG" marker, begin second test: see if the   genome contains the marker "TAG"
    if (genome.contains("tag"))
```

I'm using nested if statements and have tried adding a few things to the above line of code and got nothing!  I know I can copy/paste and change the parameters, but if there are multiple sequences in the line, I can't figure that one out.  What I would like to get from the above string is: TTCGAG*ATG***C***TGA*TTGAC*ATG***T***TAG*TAG
I can get the **C** to print, but can't make it to the **T**. My programs stop running as soon as it finds the first substring "**C**"

Comment: I think this question would be easier to answer if you gave your expected output.

Comment: or the complete code might help too (at least the one about parsing)

Comment: [That being said, I have a feeling the method of this library will solve your problems.](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#countMatches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)  If that's not what you need, there's probably another method in StringUtils that will work for you.

Comment: I think `regex` will suit your need

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood the question, but maybe this is close to what you're looking for.

```
String getSubstringBetween(String start, String[] ends) {
    int indexOfStart = genome.indexOf(start);
    if(indexOfStart >= 0) {
       int indexOfEnd = -1;
       int i = 0;
       while(i < ends.length() && indexOfEnd < 0) {
          indexOfEnd = genome.indexOf(ends[i++], indexOfStart);
       }
       if(indexOfEnd >= 0) {
          String end = ends[i - 1];
          return genome.substring(indexOfStart, indexOfEnd + end.length());
       } else {
          return genome.substring(indexOfStart);
       }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex, for sequence ATG...TGA, you can try,

```
String input = "TTCGAGATGCTGATTGACATGTTAGTAG";
Pattern pattern  = Pattern.compile("ATG(.*?)TGA");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

You will get 'C'.

If you want to get 'T' as in the posted question, you can change regex to ATG(.*?)TAG, since the prefix and suffix is sightly different.